# How to replace a specific text in a line in c#

Tags: c#, string, replace

I have the following string in a line, a part of which is to be replaced. ı am using `Regx.Replace()`.

> The address4 is found in varchar(4) is a 4.

In the above line, I must search the word "varchar" and replace the string "4" with "MAX".

Finally, the output should be like:

> The address4 is found in varchar(MAX) is a 4.

Please help me in the above issue I am facing. I am not able to replace it.

Comment: You want to replace only "4" or anything that comes with `varchar`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might this be what you are looking for?

```
Regex.Replace(s,@"varchar\([0-9]*\)", "varchar(MAX)");
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `RegEx.Replace()`, you could try this:

```
string text = "The address4 is found in varchar(4) is a 4.";
string output = Regex.Replace(text, @"varchar\([0-9]+\)", "varchar(MAX)");
```

This will replace any number inside `varchar(x)`...

[Working Example](http://ideone.com/LIfugr)

Comment: This is the correct answer, all others are incorrectly assuming that the value is always 4, but OP specified he wants to use Regex.

Answer (score 1):

You could also replace it with plain/efficient string methods:

```
string sql = "The address4 is found in varchar ( 4 ) is a 4.";
int indexOfVarchar = sql.IndexOf("varchar", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
if (indexOfVarchar >= 0)
{ 
    indexOfVarchar += "varchar".Length;
    int indexOfBrace = sql.IndexOf("(", indexOfVarchar);
    if(++indexOfBrace > 0)
    {
        int indexOfEndBrace = sql.IndexOf(")", indexOfBrace);
        if (indexOfEndBrace >= 0)
        {
            sql = string.Format("{0}MAX{1}", 
                sql.Substring(0, indexOfBrace), 
                sql.Substring(indexOfEndBrace));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this (Ref: @ReinderWit)

```
Regex reg = new Regex("varchar\\([0-9]+\\)");
string strtext = "The address4 is found in varchar(4) is a 4.";
string result= Regex.Replace(text, reg, "varchar(MAX)");
```

Comment: @ReinderWit, yes you are right! I was writing my own logic in between and didn't looked at your code :). I make your ref. in the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
String newString = yourString.Replace("varchar(4)","varchar(MAX)");
```

Comment: OP wants to search the for word "varchar" and replace it's value and in your code you directly replace "(4)" string.

Comment: Could be rewritten as `Replace("varchar(4)","varchar(MAX)")`

Comment: @Jaguar: consider `Varchar ( 4 )`

Answer (score 0):

Instead you can use extension method of the `string` class.

```
var yourString = "The address4 is found in varchar(4) is a 4.";

yourString = yourString.Replace("varchar(4)", "varchar(MAX)");
```

Answer (score 0):

String newString = Regex.Replace(yourString, "([0-9]*)", "MAX");

Comment: This would replace every number in the string with `MAX`.  Not what OP wants.

Comment: so he just needs to play around with the regex to do as he wants ;-) ... varchar\\([0-9]*\\) might fit better